# Equivalence relation for set given as matrix

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

I need a hint. My task is to proof that

- ((a11, a12), (b11, b12))
- ((a21, a22), (b21, b22))

  ∈ R ⇔ a11 + a12 + a21 + a22 = b11 + b12 + b21 + b22

R is equivalnce relation. My problem is that I have no idea how to deal with matrix.

I tried to work like in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863549/how-many-reflexive-binary-relations-there-are-on-a-finite-countable-set) and just make something like A={{a11,a12},{a21,a22}} instead of A={0,1}, but I got stuck.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: just check reflex, symmetric and transitivity. It is clear

Comment: Why don't you write what is meant by an equivalence relation? And try your self.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I saw this exact same question asked here several hours ago? Did you delete it an ask again with no changes?

Comment: @Henning: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003400/equivalnce-relation-for-sets-given-as-matrix also since this is a separate user account, you can't close as a duplicate (even though it is a word-for-word duplicate) unless there is an upvoted answer.

Comment: @Asaf: Of course I tried to google for a phrase that included the one word there's in difference between the two questions. Thanks -- we'll just close it the other way around then.

Comment: @Henning: Sure, but this shouldn't depend on someone providing an answer. Especially when the questions are identical.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a function then the relation $R$ on $X$ defined by $xRy\iff f(x)=f(y)$ is an equivalence relation. So find a proper function here on $2\times 2$-matrices.

(Why? Simply because $f(x)=f(x)$ i.e. reflexitivity, $f(x)=f(y)\Rightarrow f(y)=f(x)$ i.e. symmetry, and $f(x)=f(y)\wedge f(y)=f(z)\Rightarrow f(x)=f(z)$ i.e. transitivity)